# how to use django's registration field(s) to custom table

Tags: python, django, registration

I need to use existing field(i.e password) of registration form(it is not new field) to use on the seperate table while posting

my code is as below

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
from django.db.models.signals import post_save 

class Token(models.Model): 
  user = models.OneToOneField(User) 
  api_key=models.CharField(max_length=50) 


def create_user_token(sender, instance, created, **kwargs): 
 if created: 
   profile, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=instance) 

#this will definitely not work because i have no field name api_key on form 
post_save.connect(create_user_token, sender=User)
```

and my logic to create apikey is below

```
 #password=posted from django-registration form as i have used django-registration 
 digest = hmac.new('Secret', password, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

I am using django registration and i need to set api_key=digest whenever user register or change the password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Ilvar and Frantzdy ,you  need to use user_registered signal . Follow the steps below

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from registration.models import RegistrationProfile

attrs_dict = { 'class': 'required' }

class RegistrationFormEx(RegistrationForm):
  cell_phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict))
```

models.py

```
import hashlib
import hmac
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from registration.signals import user_registered
from userInfo.forms import RegistrationFormEx


class ExProfile(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
   cell_phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
   api_key=      models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

   def user_created(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
      form = RegistrationFormEx(data=request.POST)
      digest = hmac.new(str(request.POST['password1']), str(request.POST['username']), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
      new_user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
      //here I have added api_key hash algo, you can change it
      new_profile = ExProfile(user=new_user,cell_phone=request.POST['cell_phone'],api_key=digest)
     new_profile.save()
     return new_user

  user_registered.connect(user_created)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
import registration.backends.default.urls as regUrls
from registration.views import register
from userInfo.forms import  RegistrationFormEx


urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^accounts/register/$', register, {'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend','form_class': RegistrationFormEx}, name='registration_register'),
(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls'))

)
```

Hope you can do it now for change password stuffs, good luck

Answer (score 2):

Django-registration has a special [user_registered](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/27bccd108cde/registration/signals.py#cl-5) signal, you can take what you need from `request.POST`, for example.

For changing password you can write your own view (based on django's view) and send a signal (maybe even the same one) from there, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a change_password view I suggest adding a few lines of code to change that key.
for demonstration purposes:

```
profile = Token.objects.get(user=request.user)
#set a new api key
profile.api_key =hashlib.sha1(str(random.random()) +
                                   'app_name' +
                                 str(time.time())).hexdigest()
profile.save()
```

---